# Adding SPGroups to alets using UI

Tags: groups

I have a few SPGroups that I wish to send daily alets to but when I go to "Set an alert on this page" and type a group name in the users field it cannot be found. I am sure it exists and has users. How do I fix this?

*I must use the built in alerts and cannot create group in AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending alerts assigned to SharePoint Group is not supported by default in SharePoint 2010

But after implementing the following functionality:

- activate SharePoint Groups  for selection in people editor control
- expand a group entity to individual user entities in the text box

it will become possible to send alerts to individual users from these groups

### How it works

In Alert subscription page (New or Edit forms) type or select in People picker dialog box the SharePoint Group name

[image]

After clicking “Check names” button or OK button in People picker the SharePoint group will be  expanded  to individual users in the text box as shown below

[image]

For implementation details follow [this](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/different-ways-of-extending-people-editor-in-the-client-side-sharepoint-2010/) article

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your SPGroups are hosted outside of the pages you want to set the alerts on. Make sure the Groups you specified are on a site collection level, not a subsite level.

Comment: The Groups are on the same web/page that I am trying to assign alerts to. I have read a lot that the alerts check AD for a reference which does not exist in my case

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation I have is to create a distribution group in exchange, tie that email address to a service account, and set up alerts for that service account.

This is quite the hack and comes with the disadvantage of maintaining two lists of users (which I believe could be alleviated by setting up incoming email on the server but I haven't done it personally). Without understanding why your requirements are the way they are this is probably the best thing you can get out of the box.

There may be 3rd party / custom solutions

Comment: @TodderLegrande We are not using a single source AD for our user list so our only central area is the spUsers. I already have a main sharepoint list that tracks represents groups. I then placed them in sharepoint groups as I thought it would enable the users to manually add alerts to those groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to 2 posts that helped me achieve this very thing:

- [Send alerts to groups in SharePoint 2007](http://blog.gavin-adams.com/2007/10/26/sending-alerts-to-groups-in-sharepoint-2007/)

  - This also worked for me in 2010
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepointadminprevious/thread/c1bc4ece-27d3-4127-8ae2-ef04070416bf

  - A lot of good links and guides here too.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can't normally create alerts for SharePoint groups. Here's how:
>
> 1.E-mail enable the SharePoint group so that a distribution list/group is created in Active Directory.
>
> 2.Edit the properties of the group to change its Group Type to Security. Only security groups will show up in SharePoint's address
> book. They will show up as "domain groups" in SharePoint.
>
> 3.Give the domain group at least visitor permissions on the list that are you are creating the alerts for. Alerts won't be sent if the
> domain group doesn't have appropriate permissions. This will mean that
> you'll likely have both the SharePoint group and the domain group in
> the permissions list. Simply giving the SharePoint group permissions
> is not enough.
>
> 4.Then setup the alert and use the address book to locate the domain group. In the address book you'll see it with the form "DOMAIN\group
> name".
>
> 5.Now test out your alerts. If you have require approval turned on for the list, make sure you approve the items so alerts will be sent

http://www.amosfivesix.com/sharepoint/21-how-to-create-alerts-for-sharepoint-groups